# NestJS within a Docker container while seeing real-time changes

Tags: docker, nestjs

I want to develop using NestJS within a Docker container while seeing real-time changes. If i e.g change "hello world!" to an "another phrase", then i want that the change immediately affect also on http://localhost:3000.

Dockerfile.dev in project's root directory is:

```
FROM node:20-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g npm@10.1.0 && npm install && npm install -g @nestjs/cli
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

and docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3'

services:
  nestjs-app:
    container_name: nestjs_dev_container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

I run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

And in another terminal

```
docker exec -it nestjs_dev_container /bin/sh
```

where i escape to docker container command line:

```
/usr/src/app # cat src/app.service.ts
```

If i change app.service.ts (in a VS Code), it affect in this command result, but does nothing in http://localhost:3000, displays still only old string.

Comment: One of the design goals of Docker is generally that a container can't see the host filesystem at all.  You don't seem to be using Docker's image system, networking capability, or other features at all in this setup, just using it as a path to get a Node interpreter.  If you remove "within Docker" as a requirement, and use Node directly on your host system, can you meet your developer-oriented needs?